# isset($var) - BLADE versus raw php

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 4.2. I have a situation that I need to address in laravel blade..

WITHIN the template I have this ( and it works fine)

```
    <?php
        $faqGroup = json_decode(Lng::faq(), true);
        $lang = Lng::faq()['view_as'];
        $Q = 'question_' . $lang;
        $A = 'answer_' . $lang;

        foreach ($faqGroup as $key => $faq) {
            if (isset($faq[$Q]) && isset($faq[$A])) {
    ?>
                <?php echo $faq[$Q]; ?> <br/>
                <?php echo $faq[$A]; ?> <br/><br/>

    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
```

my output is

```
question1 eng
answer1 eng

question2 eng
answer2 eng

question3 eng
answer3 eng
```

When I try to do the same with blade

```
    <?php
        $faqGroup = json_decode(Lng::faq(), true);
        $lang = Lng::faq()['view_as'];
        $Q = 'question_' . $lang;
        $A = 'answer_' . $lang;
    ?>


    @foreach ($faqGroup as $key => $faq)

        {{ isset($faq[$Q]) }} <br/>
        {{ isset($faq[$A]) }} <br/><br/>

    @endforeach
```

my output is

```
1
1
1
```

If I try this

```
    @foreach ($faqGroup as $key => $faq)
        {{ $faq->$Q }} <br/>
    @endforeach
```

I get `Trying to get property of non-object`

If I try this

```
    @foreach ($faqGroup as $key => $faq)

        {{ $faq[$Q] }} <br/>

    @endforeach
```

I get `Illegal string offset 'question_eng'`

**Help?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your original code and logic which is working - your @foreach loop should be like this

```
@forreach ($faqGroup as $key => $faq)
    @if (isset($faq[$Q]) && isset($faq[$A])) 
        {{ $faq[$Q] }} <br/>
        {{ $faq[$A] }} <br/><br/>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: That works, thank you. According to Laravel documentation your code should do the same as {{{ isset($faq[$Q]) }}}

Comment: No - that is not correct. The difference between `{{` and `{{{` in Laravel 4 is only if it the output is escaped or not. It has nothing to do with whether the data is set or not